# How can I replace column value with getdate() only for specific values in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have a Column termination with  some of the values '1900-01-01' by default,I wanted to replace them with the Current date.which function can i use to do so

Answer (score 1):

Use the `case` statement:

```
select (case when col = '1900-01-01' then getdate() else col end)
```

Or do something similar in an `update` statement to permanently change the values in the table.

Or change the default definition for the column to `getdate()` from `1900-01-01`.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE TableName
SET ColumnName = GETDATE()
WHERE ColumnName = '1900-01-01'